# How I can set general getter for an existing object?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, default-value, ecmascript-next

I'm interested in adding common getter which would executes on every property get call of an existing object.
All we know how to set getter for specific property, but can we set getter which's callback would be involved during getting every property in an object?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for this.

Comment: If it explicitly needs to be using the existing object, then this isn't possible. Proxies can do this but would require a new object, and also proxies are pretty complicated and in my opinion usually not a good idea.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the getter to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're thinking of a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Specifically, you can use the [`handler.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) to intercept any property.

#### Example

```js
const guitar = {
  stringCount: 6,
  model: 'Stratocaster',
};

// this is where the magic happens
const genericHandler = {
  get: function(target, propertyName) {
    // at this point, you can do anything you want – we'll just log the attempt
    console.log(`Attempted to get ${propertyName}`);

    // this will return the original value
    return target[propertyName];
  }
};

const proxiedGuitar = new Proxy(guitar, genericHandler);

// This outputs
//   Attempted to get stringCount
//   6
console.log(proxiedGuitar.stringCount);

// you can even write a handler for non-existent properties
console.log(proxiedGuitar.pickupType);
```

This is a simplified and incomplete example which may not work in some cases. See @loganfsmyth's clarification in the comment below.

Comment: This is a bad `get` handler. `get` is passed 3 arguments, so you should be using `Reflect.get` to look up the property to return. This is also an incomplete proxy membrane, so you should mention that this will break in many cases, like if the `guitar` object were stored in a weakmap or were a class using private class properties.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for your clarification! You're right. My intention indeed wasn't to provide production-ready code (though that's perhaps what many users of this site expect...), just a simple answer to a simple question – to introduce the _concept_ of Proxies.